# Can I use single parameter in better-sqlite.get() or better-sqlite.all() multiple times in the same statement

Tags: sqlite, better-sqlite3

I'm using better-sqlite in node to access an sqlite3 database.

Is there a way to pass a single parameter to `all()` or `get()` and use it multiple times in the statement. At the moment I'm doing this:

```
const statement = `SELECT * FROM table WHERE
        column_1 = ?
    OR
        column_2 = ?
    OR
        column_3 = ?
`;

const param = 'something';
const results = db.prepare(statement).all(
    param,
    param,
    param
);
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
const statement = `SELECT * FROM table WHERE
        column_1 = ?1
    OR
        column_2 = ?1
    OR
        column_3 = ?1
`;

const param = 'something';
const results = db.prepare(statement).all(
    param
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
const results = db.prepare(statement).all(
    { 1: param }
);
```